# iOS - How to print value in textfield using delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, delegates

I am new to iOS. I have some problem do you have some solution for it? I am not able to print the json value in textfield 
This is my `contactViewController.m` file:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad]; 
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        fname.text=@"Hello";
    }
```

After the view is loaded **hello** value is shown in the text box, but when I call list button to get the json values:

```
-(IBAction)list:(id)sender{
    vedant=[[WebserviceViewController alloc]init];

    [vedant listContacts];

}
```

Then from `webserviceViewController.m` I pass the jsonResponse to the same file i.e `contactViewController.m` and parse the json value and print it but it does not shows the value in text field

```
-(void)allContacts:(NSString *)JSONResponse{
    NSLog(@"%@",JSONResponse);


    NSData *jsonData = [JSONResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //
    NSError *err;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
    int accCount =[json count];

    for(int i=0;i<accCount;i++){

        NSData *jsonData = [JSONResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        //

        //   NSLog(@"%@",JSONResponse);

        NSError *err;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&err];

        NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"first_name"]];


        NSLog(@"%@",firstName);    //this prints the actual first name in console But

        fname.text=firstName;
        NSLog(@"%@",fname.text);   //it prints "(Null)" in console
    }

}
```

Do I need to create delegate to pass value?

Yes, then any help of creating such delegate some article or example.

Comment: fname is equal to nil?

Comment: the function `allContacts:` is implemented in webserviceViewController.m and you want to show the value in `fname` that is in contactViewController.m, Am I right?

Comment: yes, and the fname value is nil even if i put some value when the view loads

Comment: the function `allContacts` will "only" show a value on this textField or this is just a test?

Comment: the error that you have is that you are assigning the value to a textField that do not exist, `fname` make reference to property of webserviceViewController.m, not to the field of contactViewController.m that is visible

Comment: are u setting the property ?

Comment: check the connections of ur textfield again...

Comment: I have created this function to parse the json value because the json response gives multiple value such as first name last name phone no etc.

Comment: if you move this function from webserviceViewController.m to contactViewController.m it will work

Comment: @Nag_iphone Sorry i did't get you?

Comment: allContant is in contactViewController.m file

Comment: How did you declare that textField ??

Comment: If you mean the fname is equal to nil when you use it.You can type watchpoint set variable -w write fname in console when you sure the fname is not equal to nil.Then app will stop when the fname is given a new value.

Comment: i mean r u declare like @property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField * fname;

Comment: I had declared it like the way u said and @synthesize it in .m file

Comment: self.fname.text=firstName

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",self.fname.text);

Comment: It's not working. It prints (null).
I have 1 more question it prints null but at IB it shows the value hello in textfield which printed in viewDidLoad() function.

Comment: r u creating programtically (or ) XIB?

Comment: using XIB and i also tried printing value in list() function like hello new it prints hello new in fname textfield

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25505/discussion-between-arun-and-nag-iphone)

Comment: you are not returning the data to your contactViewController.m - you just print the value at your webserviceViewController.m that b/c you can find the value in viewController. Give some more info what is doing - (void) listContacts in your webserviceViewController than will be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Delegate i solved this problems

In my `contactViewController.m` file:

```
-(IBAction)list:(id)sender{
    vedant=[[WebserviceViewController alloc]init];
    vedant.delegate=self;
    [vedant listContacts];

}
```

In `webserviceViewController.h` I created my own delegate

```
@protocol WebservicesDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)allContacts:(NSString *)JSONResponse;
@end
```

then in `webserviceViewController.m` file after getting the json response from backend i am  sending the response back to my `contactViewController.m` file using this code

```
[self.delegate allContacts:jsonResponse];
```

the compiler comes back to  `allContacts` function in `contactViewController.m` file this code is same i didn't change the code now it prints the value.

```
-(void)allContacts:(NSString *)JSONResponse{
NSLog(@"%@",JSONResponse);


NSData *jsonData = [JSONResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
int accCount =[json count];

for(int i=0;i<accCount;i++){

    NSData *jsonData = [JSONResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //

    //   NSLog(@"%@",JSONResponse);

    NSError *err;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&err];

    NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"first_name"]];


    NSLog(@"%@",firstName);    //this prints the actual first name in console But

    fname.text=firstName;
    NSLog(@"%@",fname.text);   //it prints "(Null)" in console
}

}
```

I think because i was trying to get data from different view and wanted to display the data in another view was the problem.
But by creating the delegate the problem was solves and i can easily send the data from one view to another view.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `fname` isn't `nil`. If you forgot to properly connect it in Interface Builder, `fname` will be `nil` and all messages sent to it (like `setText:`) will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Please First check that you have bind your textfield with your fname variable. If yes then try to assign value using this:

```
fname.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
```

Just try this. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: No, it does't print any value but now it shows Hello in fname field.

Answer (score 0):

Get your first name(i.e value from json) into global value and assign that global value into your textfield . It is so simple. if you still have doubts than reply i'll post sample code

Answer (score 0):

txtName.text=firstname; OR
txtName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];